# Is this by Ardens Lemma? | Finite Automata

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata

I need your help. When I get this question like this [image]

and when I see the **answer** it look like this

[image]

This must be by Ardens Lemma right?
I just want to why teacher eliminated first E1 then E2, why not E2 then E1?

**Second Question:** I want to know do I have to first convert NFA to DFA then do by Ardens Lemma?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** Probably because $E_1$ does not appear on the right hand side of its own equation. Otherwise you could not eliminate it so easily, becuase replacing it by the right hand side would just lead to new occurences.

**Question 2:** Arden's rule applies to equations of sets. It does not matter which kind of automaton these equations are derived from. But from a deterministic one you get easier equations.

Comment: ah I see. So its better to Convert from (e) NFA to DFA ?

Comment: Sir I have another question! If there is a question where it showing DFA or NFA tabel can I use by Ardens Lemma? or can you tell me another simple method?

Comment: From your answer Question1 What do you mean by Right hand side?

Comment: Also do you have a good excerise to practise step by step in Ardents Lemma? :)

Comment: Hope you can answer all my questions :) ty